# Hochschild cohomology of a smooth manifold: a sheaf?

Tags: homology-cohomology, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology

It can be shown that the Hochschild cohomology of the algebra of smooth function on $X$ is naturally isomorphic to the sheaf of de Rham currents.

But is it possible to see from the very definition of Hochschild cohomology that this is a sheaf?

The Hochschild complex is given by continuous $(n + 1)$-linear forms on the space $C^\infty(X)$: $C^n = \{ \phi \mid C^\infty(X)^{n + 1} \to \mathbb{C}$} and with differential $b \colon C^{n-1} \to C^{n}$ given by
$$
  b\phi(f_0, \dotsc, f_n)
  = (-1)^n \phi(f_n f_0, f_1, \dotsc) + \sum_{0 \leq i < n} \phi(\dotsc, f_i f_{i+1}, \dotsc) \,.
$$

Thanks